# LINQ Group by error: "does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy'"

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List that I need to group by. In the list I add this object:

```
private class MyObject {

        private System.Drawing.Color color;
        private string title;            

        public MyObject(System.Drawing.Color color, string title)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set { title = value; }
        }

        public System.Drawing.Color Color
        {
            get { return color; }
            set { color = value; }
        }

}
```

I create my List as:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<MyObject> mList = new       System.Collections.Generic.List<MyObject >();
```

Then I try to group the content:

```
var groupedList = mList.GroupBy(c => new {c.Title} ).ToList();
```

And that is when I get the error. Any ideas? How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: And an error saying that ... ???

Comment: @sll `... does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy'`

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.Linq?

Comment: What version of `.NET` are you running?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those kinds of errors typically mean you aren't including `System.Linq` in your using list.  Try throwing this at the top of your code file:

`using System.Linq;`

Comment: The error message is so stupid, the developer are miserably, desperately looking for `definition for 'GroupBy'` because a missing import

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a reference to the System.Linq namespace?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `using System.Linq` to the file, at the top or inside of the namespace.

`GroupBy` isn't actually a method of the `List` class, it's an extension method that is defined in `System.Linq`.  When you add a `using` statement to that namespace it allows all extension methods in that namespace to be resolve to any types they extend for the file the `using` is in.

Some unrelated notes:

1. you probably also want to add a `using System.Collections.Generic`, as well as several other common namespaces to the top of that file, and likely most others.  Typing out `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyObject> mList = new       System.Collections.Generic.List<MyObject >();` just makes me cringe.  Once you add that `using` you'll only need: `List<MyObject> mList = new List<MyObjecT>();`.
2. You probably don't want to create a new anonymous class for your grouping.  It will work, but it'll make using the results that much more annoying without adding anything useful.  Just do: `mList.GroupBy(c => c.Title )` if you only want to group on the `Title`.